# how to change and save a matrix in another document in python?

Tags: python, matrix

I have a 48 by 36 matrix  of zeros in a text document and I want to replace random values into ones and then save it. Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import random
a = np.zeros((48,36), dtype=np.int)

x = random.randrange(48)
y = random.randrange(36)
a[x,y] = 1

f = open('Earth_Village2', 'w')
f.write(str(a))
f.close()
print('done!')
```

but the text document shows this:

```
[[0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]
 ..., 
 [0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]]
```

and when I have a smaller matrix (10 x 10) it does work:

(x = 7 and y = 7)

```
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

how can I show the entire 48 by 36 matrix?

Comment: That's what `numpy` is *supposed* to do with large arrays, but why are you saving the string representation anyway? There are several options for persisting those objects to files [built right in](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/routines.io.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set this option in your script:

```
np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.nan)
```

See more details [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html).